# React text editor which I can customize

Tags: text-editor

I'm looking for a text editor that I can use in react and I can customize the look of it like styling the drop down or select box, adding my own icons and the rest, but with the same functionalities? for example I want to change he look of the font select box and style it like how I want it to look like

Comment: I'm not sur to understand your question, you are looking for a text editor or how to change styles of components rendered?

Comment: You can use SlateJS, DraftJS or Quill. SlateJS is latest and easiest to start with.

Comment: @ElPandario i'm looking for a text editor, that i can customise the style of the toolbar for example so it suits a ui design i've been given